# Can't Log to an aspx form from Android

Tags: android, http, logging

I have a code to make an httpPost, but i can't log using the parameters in the array, but if i make all the complete url i will log with no problem !, what am i missing ?

```
 String URL = "http://domain.com/projexct/form.aspx"; //won't work
//    String URL = "http://domain.com/projexct/form.aspx?user=aa&pass=11";  
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);


                     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "aa"));
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "11"));
                     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));




                     // Execute HTTP Post Request 
                     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**EDIT1**
It doesn't throw and error, but if i use the parames in namevaluePairs it shows just the login page, if i use the URL commented it will actualy log in.

Comment: that's because an aspx is a web page.  You need to be using the service behind the aspx page.

Comment: in my code behind i have all the programming to make the validations, see my edit above

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK in my HTML code from aspx it shows `<form id="login" action="login.aspx" method="post" name="login">`